# Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 -- mongodb

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos

A few minutes ago I have been getting problem with my mongodb database, the mongodb service is not working and I don't know why. The database service was working properly for long time but today I got an error and my mongodb service was stopped.

Looking on the mongodb log file I found the following:

Wed Aug  7 17:48:19.987 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took: 55ms
Wed Aug  7 17:48:20.594 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: WriteBackManager::cleaner took: 21ms
Wed Aug  7 17:49:23.203 [TTLMonitor] query admin.system.indexes query: { expireAfterSeconds: { $exists: true } } ntoreturn:0 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:23633919 nreturned:0 reslen:20 23636ms

I don't have any idea about what is happening here, because is a first time that I get that error, so I'd be grateful if somebody help me with that.

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching for a while on the web, I found a solution that was good for me and I hope that if anyone has the same problems as me, this may assist them.

Please click here : [Recover MongoDB Data following Unexpected Shutdown](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/)

Best regards.